# custom post list item shortcode

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

how to add this 2 short code in one, because I want to use this in several categories. please also inform me how to add category in this short code.

now my short code is `[featured-post]`
I want this `[featured-post='category name']`

exactly, I need a shortcode 5 post will display from a category but first post have trumbanail then title then excerpt then rest of 4 list cetegory post only show title and permalink

```
    function featured_post_shortcode($atts){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(), 
    $atts, 'featured-post' ) );

    $q = new WP_Query(
        array( 'category' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'post_type' => 'post')
        );
$list = '';

while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    //get the ID of your post in the loop
    $id = get_the_ID();


    $post_thumbnail= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'lead-thumbnail' ); 
    $list .= '

        <div class="featured">
                            '.$post_thumbnail.'
            <a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>
            <p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>
            </div>  

    ';        
endwhile;
$list.= '</div>';
wp_reset_query();
return $list;
}
add_shortcode('featured-post', 'featured_post_shortcode');  



function more_item_shortcode($atts){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(), 
    $atts, 'featured-post' ) );

    $q = new WP_Query(
        array( 'category' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => '4', 'post_type' => 'post')
        );
$list = '<ul>';

while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    //get the ID of your post in the loop
    $id = get_the_ID();



    $list .= 

        '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';


endwhile;
$list.= '</ul>';
wp_reset_query();
return $list;
}
add_shortcode('more-item', 'more_item_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function featured_post_shortcode($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts( array('cat' => ''), $atts));

    $q = new WP_Query(
            array( 'cat' => $cat, 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'post_type' => 'post')
            //Use category slug: array( 'category_name' => $cat, 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'post_type' => 'post')
        );
    $count = 0;
    if( $q->have_posts() ): 
        $output = '<ul>';
        while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post(); $count++; global $post;

            if($count == 1){
                $output .= '
                    <div class="featured">'.
                        get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'lead-thumbnail').
                        '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>
                        <p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>
                    </div>
                ';
            }else{
                $output .= '
                    <li>
                        <a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>
                    </li>
                ';  
            }
        endwhile; 
        $output .= '</ul>';
    endif;
wp_reset_query();
return $output;
}
add_shortcode('featured-post', 'featured_post_shortcode');
```

if you want to use the category slug then use `category_name` otherwise use `cat` which takes the category ID

in your callback: `[featured-post cat="1"]`

Comment: i want to add a <div class ="more item"> in ul li. first post dont need ul and li